# haskell beginner - my simple sort

Tags: haskell

I have this code for sorting list of even number of items:

```
sort [] = []
sort l = sortN l (length l)

sortN l 0 = l
sortN l n = sortN (swap l) (n - 1)

swap [] = []
swap (a:b:t) | a <= b = a : b : (swap t)
swap (a:b:t) | b <  a = b : a : (swap t)
```

and I am stuck. For some reason, which I don't understand it returns results as if only one swap was always called.

Also, please do not post here better and more efficient ways how to sort. I am aware of them. I want to know why this is wrong, not other solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: I know you said you didn't want suggestions for other algorithms, but that's tough. I'll suggest merge sort, which is particularly pretty in Haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you are only considering the same pairs of element on each pass.  Consider:

```
swap (a:b:t) | a <= b = a : b : (swap t)
swap (a:b:t) | b <  a = b : a : (swap t)
```

What if we have a list `[4,1,1,1]`?

```
swap [4,1,1,1] = 1 : 4 : swap [1,1] = 1:4:1:1:[]
```

Ok, now lets look at the next iteration of `sortN` and its call to `swap`:

```
swap [1,4,1,1] = 1 : 4 : swap [1,1]
```

So you see, `swap` implicitly assumes every pair of elements is ordered within the list.  Instead consider the implementation `a: swap (b:t)` and `b : swap (a : t)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer you a working version (there was the one-element case missing from `swap` so as far as I see you will run into trouble else:

```
swap []  = []
swap [a] = [a]
swap (a:b:t)
  | a <= b    = a : swap (b:t)
  | otherwise = b : swap (a:t)
```

I will not be tempted into giving you a different algorithm but still you don't need to run `swap xs` `length xs` times - you just have to run it till the output is not changing anymore:

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort = fix swap

swap :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
swap []  = []
swap [a] = [a]
swap (a:b:t)
  | a <= b    = a : swap (b:t)
  | otherwise = b : swap (a:t)

fix :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
fix f x = let x' = f x
          in if x' /= x then fix f x' else x
```

`fix` here will do exactly that - it applies `f` to `x` till the result is not changing anymore.

for example:

- `sort [3,6,1,3,2]` will call `swap` only 4 times
- `sort [1..10]` it will be called only once

---

### testing your implementations

maybe you are interested in how you can easily check your implementations - here is a QuickCheck test (I used to verify my solution too) that does this:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

isSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
isSorted []  = True
isSorted [_] = True
isSorted (a:b:t) = a<=b && isSorted (b:t)

checkSortAlg :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> IO ()
checkSortAlg sortAlg = quickCheck test
  where
    test xs = isSorted $ sortAlg xs
```

you just have to run it like this (for example in ghci):

```
checkSortAlg sort
```

it should print `+++ OK, passed 100 tests.`

here is what it does for for the version with the missing `swap [a] = [a]` case:

```
(after 3 tests and 1 shrink): 
Exception:
  SimpleSort.hs:(9,1)-(12,30): Non-exhaustive patterns in function swap
[0]
```

this tells you that after 3 tests it used some list that after shrinking to `[0]` still threw the `Non-exhaustive patterns` exception - so it basically tells you to look for the single element case here ;) - of course the compiler should have too